# Waiting for current user in .Net Parse LogInAsync

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

This is the first time I have wrote a program using parse and I cannot get parse to log me in. In the code below the current user is always set to null. I need to be able to login and proceed to the next activity in the app.

```
        public static async void correctCredentials(string username, string password){

        try{
            await ParseUser.LogInAsync (username, password);
            if(ParseUser.CurrentUser != null)
                parseloggedIN = true;


        } catch{
            //Nothing here
        }
```